# Subscription validation error handling

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently trying to handle the exception, when a subscription request can't be validated in time, using the Graph SDK. Unfortunately i am not really sure how to achieve this. The exception thrown when a subscription isn't validated in time is:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InvalidRequest
>       Message: Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to 
>       this request.

The [HttpStatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) in the ServiceException is "BadRequest" but just this isn't enough to distinguish the error from other common errors since i want to handle them differently. The ServiceException  also contains an Error property with a string property called "Code", which contains "InvalidRequest" in my case. The [GraphErrorCode](https://github.com/MIchaelMainer/GraphAPI/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph/Enums/GraphErrorCode.cs) enum in the Graph SDK contained this code so i used it with the "IsMatch" method in the ServiceException:

```
catch (ServiceException serviceException)
{
     var invRequest = GraphErrorCode.InvalidRequest.ToString();
     if(serviceException.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
     {
          if (serviceException.IsMatch(invRequest))
          {
              // do something
          }
      }
}
```

"InvalidRequest" is defined in the [graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors) as:

> The request is malformed or incorrect.

Considering this i still think my ErrorHandling isn't enough to just catch this specific error.

What i want to know is:

- Is using the "GraphErrorCode" enum even correct.
- Is there a way to handle this specific error without just comparing the exception message ("Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request") with a hard coded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing an outdated library (by over 2 years). The correct SDK for this is the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet#microsoft-graph-net-client-library). It includes an far more recent [error code enumeration](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Enums/GraphErrorCode.cs).

As for processing the error, the code is typically enough for handling exceptions. The message content is useful for debugging since it often includes more granular information (what exactly failed, which properties were invalid, etc.). My general rule of thumb is to use the `code` for handling errors but log both `code` and `message` properties for debugging.

The import piece to understand is that different endpoints may surface the same error code for different reasons. A `BadRequest` may mean something different when issuing a `GET` against a `user` resource than it does when issuing a `POST` to `/events`.  Your handler should take into account both the *action* and the *error*.

Here is an example error returned when sending an invalid request (`/v1.0/me/a`):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038/a",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "fd4c8b27-26af-4b07-a5be-5efb139d1eb7",
            "date": "2018-05-22T14:39:02"
        }
    }
}
```

If all I handled was the `BadRequest`, my handler would likely sufficient. I can handle the error and keep the user moving forward. In my log however I store both `BadRequest` and `Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038/a` so that I can properly file a bug in the code.

Another option might be to do some additional parsing. Lets say that `/a` doesn't *always* return an error. Maybe `/a` works fine for AAD accounts but not for MSA users (FTR, `/a` is entirely fictitious). If this were the case, I might also want to parse the `message` and see if the `BadRequest` included "Unsupported segment type" and handle it a bit differently than a `BadRequest` that didn't include that message.

Comment: Just for clarification. Can the error JSON representations code property contain HttpErrorCodes (since you used BadRequest in your example which isn't mentioned in the [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors)? Also to your last point. Wouldn't it be unreliable to parse the message because it may change? Thank you for the elaborate answer btw.

Comment: I generally agree that parsing messages is less than ideal. They certainly can change. To help mitigate this a bit, I tend to parse for keywords rather than the full message. It isn't perfect but it's a bit better. As for the `BadRequest`, it actually is in that doc ( first item, `400 - Bad Request`). The JSON doesn't carry the HTTP code since it's already in the response header that came with the JSON payload.